# Building product in $\Bbb N$ using the function $s: n\mapsto n+1$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, definition, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

using the Peano's axioms we can give a description of the set of natural numbers.

Let's consider the functions

$s: \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ defined by $s(n)=n+1$

and

$f^n=\begin{cases}
id, &\text{ if } n=0 \\
f\circ f^{n-1},&\text { else}
\end{cases}$

We can define the sum of two natural numbers in the following way: $n+m= s^n(m)$

How can I define the product using the power function and the function $s$?

Answer (score 1):

Addition is defined as repeated application of the successor function $s$.

Similiarly, multiplication is defined as repeated addition.

If $n+m=s^n(m)\equiv \text{add}_n(m) = \text{add}_n \circ \text{add}_m(0)$, then we define multiplication by

$$n\cdot m = \text{add}_n^{m}(0) = (s^n)^m(0)$$

Comment: I dont know how to tag you. Do you think is it correct what i wrote down?

Comment: @JohnPi No. See my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried defining operation in different ways.

Sum: $D(0)=m$ and $D(n+1)=D(n)+1$

$m+n= s^n(m)$

Product: $D(0)=m×0=0$ and $D(1)=m×1=m$
and $D(n+1)= D(n)+n$

$m×n=(s^n)^m= id$ if n=0 or m=0 else  $\sum_{i=1}^{m}s^{n}$

Now that i defined the product i can say : $(s^n)^m$=s^(nm)

Power: $D(0)= m^0=1$ and $D(n)=D(n-1)×n$

$m^n= 1$ if n=0 else

$\sum_{i_1=1}^{m}(\sum_{i_2=1}^{m}(...(\sum_{i_n=1}^{m}s(0))))$
nested sum repeated n times

Are they correct? Would you write them differentely?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Try to format your question with MathJax. For example, you can write D(0)=m to $D(0)=m$ by adding dollar signs on both sides.

Comment: I ve tried, now it should be better

Comment: @JohnPi I find your answer quite confusing. For example, you define and use $D$ quite inconsistently - what is $D$? Also, you should not be using the $\sum$ symbol, if the entire point is to define addition and multiplication - what does $\sum$ mean? Please be more careful with your definitions, maybe make a new post about this?